# Convergence change for PCA when upgrading python 3.6 to 3.7 and scikit-learn 0.19 to 0.23

Tags: python, scikit-learn, upgrade, pca

I'm using classical PCA from scikit-learn for a classification model using LogisticRegression for a dataframe having 22 000 rows * 45 000 columns, data are scaled, but both have convergence issues when I upgraded python 3.6 to 3.7 and scikit-learn 0.19 to 0.23.

```
raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge") LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

I have no NaN in my dataframe, but it can be a memory issue.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
   
n_components = int(X_main.shape[0] / 5)

pca = PCA(n_components=n_components)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(X_main)

principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data=principalComponents)
```

I changed nothing else, I resolved this by changing some hyper-parameters but i wonder why this appears, I've tested when I rollback to older versions and convergence error "disappear".

I don't know why, is there a warning now for convergence or is it computing another way, or other reasons ?

Thanks for you advice :)

Comment: Please add a snippet of the code that you are running

Comment: The answers here provide some other reasons this error is raised: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827594/raise-linalgerrorsvd-did-not-converge-linalgerror-svd-did-not-converge-in-m

Comment: Does this answer your question? [raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge") LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in matplotlib pca determination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827594/raise-linalgerrorsvd-did-not-converge-linalgerror-svd-did-not-converge-in-m)

Comment: yep i've read that, I'm thinking that there is a memory error, but i don't understand why it's raised when i upgrade my libraries and disappear when I rollback