How to fix SVD misconvergence
Full error code: raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
I'm currently using a plethora of packages for a biological alignment (VALIS being the main one) and I keep running into this error which is sourced to many different modules within the imported packages.
I wasn't really sure how to troubleshoot this since it seemed to be coming from the imported modules, however I tried downgrading my numpy but to no avail. If anyone can help with this, I'd really appreciate it. Oh and I'm also decently new to coding so the more simply worded your answer, the better.
VERSIONS:
Python 3.9.6 (mandated by VALIS)
Numpy 1.25.0 (I've tried 1.26.4 too, but cannot downgrade lower than 1.25.0 due to wheel construction issues).

What is the range of values that you are inputting? Do they contains infs or NaNs? Is the numerical dynamic range large (i.e., some very tiny numbers and some very large ones)? Do any of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827594/raise-linalgerrorsvd-did-not-converge-linalgerror-svd-did-not-converge-in-m help?

Something in this program or the libraries used by this program is calling np.linalg.lstsq() with invalid arguments. Can you post a traceback to narrow it down?
